# Who has the same job as their initial job

Tags: sql, postgresql

**psql (9.6.1, server 9.5.5)**

```
hr=> select employee_id, job_id from employees;
 employee_id |   job_id   
-------------+------------
         100 | AD_PRES
         101 | AD_VP
         102 | AD_VP
         103 | IT_PROG
         104 | IT_PROG
         107 | IT_PROG
         124 | ST_MAN
         141 | ST_CLERK
         142 | ST_CLERK
         143 | ST_CLERK
         144 | ST_CLERK
         149 | SA_MAN
         174 | SA_REP
         176 | SA_REP
         178 | SA_REP
         200 | AD_ASST
         201 | MK_MAN
         202 | MK_REP
         205 | AC_MGR
         206 | AC_ACCOUNT
(20 rows)



hr=> select employee_id, job_id from job_history;
 employee_id |   job_id   
-------------+------------
         102 | IT_PROG
         101 | AC_ACCOUNT
         101 | AC_MGR
         201 | MK_REP
         104 | ST_CLERK
         124 | ST_CLERK
         200 | AD_ASST
         176 | SA_REP
         176 | SA_MAN
         200 | AC_ACCOUNT
(10 rows)
```

The task is from the student's guide on Oracle Database 10g. I just cloned the schema and data for PostgreSQL.

So, the task is:
**Create a report that lists the employee IDs and job IDs of those employees who currently have a job title that is the same as their job title when they were initially hired by the company (that is, they changed jobs but have now gone back to doing their original job).**

My solution is:

```
select 
    employee_id, job_id from employees 
intersect 
    (select distinct on (employee_id) 
    employee_id, job_id from job_history 
    order by employee_id, start_date);
```

But there are published Practice Solutions for this course. And in it we can find:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,job_id
FROM
    employees
INTERSECT
    SELECT
    employee_id,job_id
    FROM
    job_history;
```

But their solution is not about initial hiring. Who is wrong: me or they?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Definitely you are are right, but note these: a) Oracle does not have `DISTINCT ON` b) neither of these queries take account *they changed jobs but have now gone back to doing their original job* (so f.ex. your solution will list those too, who never changed their jobs).